# Mysql Query takes too much time to execute

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance

So I have to tables, `products_used` aprox 600MB and `products_language_description` which is about 5MB, but the thing is that this query never finishes running...

I have tried REPAIR,OPTIMIZE ANALYZE, I'm out of ideas how to improve this...

```
SELECT pu.products_id, count(pu.products_id) as products_count, p.products_name,
pu.time_used FROM products_used pu, products_language_description p
WHERE pu.merchant_id='69'
AND p.products_id=pu.products_id GROUP BY products_id ORDER BY products_count
DESC LIMIT 0, 20



CREATE TABLE `products_used` (
    `products_used_id` INT(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `plans_key` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `products_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `customers_id` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `merchant_id` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `time_used` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    PRIMARY KEY (`products_used_id`),
    INDEX `plans_key` (`plans_key`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT=24625441;

CREATE TABLE `products_language_description` (
    `products_id` INT(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `products_description` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    `products_name` TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `products_help_info` LONGBLOB NOT NULL,
    `products_language` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`products_id`, `products_language`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Comment: So have you tried doing an EXPLAIN on your query, or considered putting appropriate indexes on the tables? (e.g. an index on `products_used.product_id` perhaps, or on `products_used.merchant_id`

Comment: It's usually a good rule of thumb to put index's on any field you are going to be using a WHERE clause against, especially when there will be duplicate values in that field.

Comment: I would highly recommend using Explicit instead of Implicit joins

Answer (score 2):

Try adding index to `product_id` & `merchant_id` fields on `products_used` table

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT pu.products_id, count(pu.products_id) as products_count,
       p.products_name, pu.time_used
FROM products_used pu join
     products_language_description p
     on p.products_id = pu.products_id
WHERE pu.merchant_id = '69'
GROUP BY pu.products_id
ORDER BY products_count DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

You want an index on `products_used(merchant_id, products_id)`.  In MySQL, sometimes you can rewrite an aggregation query using a correlated subquery to improve results:

```
SELECT pu.products_id,
       (select count(*)
        from products_language_description p
        where p.products_id = pu.products_id
       ) as products_count,
       p.products_name, pu.time_used
FROM products_used pu
WHERE pu.merchant_id = '69'
ORDER BY products_count DESC
LIMIT 0, 20;
```

This replaces the outer `group by` with an aggregation in the correlated query that *should* just used the primary key index.

EDIT:

Wait.  Your problem are these two definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE `products_used` (
    . . . 
    `products_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
)
   . . .
CREATE TABLE `products_language_description` (
    `products_id` INT(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     . . . 
)
```

The join conditions use a different data type.  Fix the table structures so the columns have the same type (using `alter table . . .`) or by rebuilding them.

Comment: I have added the indexes and is running now using the old query, but it displays, but very slow, so now regarding your query I get an error: `SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'p) as products_count, p.products_name, pu.time_used
FROM products_used pu WHERE' at line 1`

Comment: I have made products_id INT(5) still the same problems

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at you WHERE section.

WHERE 
  pu.merchant_id='69'
  AND p.products_id=pu.products_id GROUP BY products_id

You are comparing two different data types:

- `products_id` **INT(5)** NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
- `products_id` **BIGINT(20)** NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

Also, you are using single quotes in an unnecesary way:

- pu.merchant_id=**'69'**

Maybe you need to create some indeces in the first case. A foreign key helps too!

Maybe this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon mentioned, I would have an extend the index on your products used table to (merchant_id, product_id, time_used ) so it is a covering index and does not have to go to the raw data to get your count().  Now, it appear weird to me that you would have multiple instances of the SAME "products_id" in the products_used table for a given merchant, but that's another thing.

I would do an internal prequery of the product ID, count and time SPECIFIC TO THE MERCHANT you want.  Otherwise, as in Gordon's query sample, I was prequerying EVERY Product first, then outside of that getting those for the merchant.

I am proposing prequery the internal products used specific to the merchant, then once THAT is returned, get the product name.

```
SELECT 
      JustByMerchant.products_id, 
      JustByMerchant.products_count, 
      p.products_name,
      JustByMerchant.time_used 
   FROM
      ( select 
              pu.products_id, 
              count(*) as products_count, 
              pu.time_used 
           from
              products_used pu
           where
              pu.merchant_id = 69
           group by 
              pu.products_id
           order by
              COUNT(*) DESC
           limit 
              0, 20 ) JustByMerchant
        JOIN products_language_description p
           ON JustByMerchant.products_id = p.products_id
```